# What is prefered to use in alt text "&" or "&amp;" for screenreader users?

Tags: xhtml, cross-browser, accessibility, screen-readers

Services `&amp;` Products

or

Services & Products

**Update:**

How popular screen readers and text only browsers will handle `&amp;`?

Comment: All known entity references are getting replaced by the text they represent. So `&amp;` is getting replaced by `&#38;` that is then replaced by the character `&` it represents. So `&amp;` in HTML is displayed as `&`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Screen readers will read "&" as "and", and text-only browsers will display it as "&".

The reason you write `&amp;` is because "&" is a special character in XHTML and must be escaped. Any browser/screenreader that understands XHTML knows that `&amp;` is the escaped ampersand ('&') and will display it as such, or read it aloud as "and".

If you're writing an XHTML document, it's not a case of how to make your alt-text more screenreader friendly - you *must* replace your bare ampersands with `&amp;` or risk your document not validating and potentially displaying incorrectly.

Answer (score 6):

In HTML — it doesn't matter (since the ampersand is followed by a space).

In XHTML — `&` is a well-formedness error and is completely unacceptable.

Comment: It won't. The browser will parse the HTML or XHTML and generate a DOM which it will render. The screen reader will then read what is on the screen with hints from the browser.

Comment: As a rule of thumb — write good HTML and don't expect screen readers to require you to make errors.

Answer (score 3):

You must [escape the plain `&` with a character reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xml-20001006#dt-chardata) like `&amp;` in order to have a valid XHTML document:

> The ampersand character (`&`) […] may appear in their literal form only when used as markup delimiters, or within a comment, a processing instruction, or a CDATA section. If they are needed elsewhere, they must be escaped using either numeric character references or the strings "`&amp;`" […]

Comment: Do I need a valid XHTML document for my normal website?

Answer (score 0):

Always escape the ampersand character with the proper character encoding.  In HTML it is &amp; or &#38;.  In URI it is %26 and not either of the previous two.  Not escaping syntax characters will cause XML to fail.  If your HTML is ever to be integrated or interpreted by an XML engine your code will break.

Comment: The proper code for `&` is `%26` and not `%38`. And note that `href="foo%26bar"` is different to `href="foo&#38;bar"` as the former value declaration will be evaluated to `foo%26bar` while the latter will be evaluated to `foo&bar`.

Comment: You are correct that the correct URI escape for the ampersand is %26, but href="food&#38;bar" is invalid URI syntax.  The escape that you mention is a result of preprocessing from a user-agent application and not a consider for URI itself.  This is why people typically escape characters in URI erroneously.